# How to limit number of accociations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Straight to subject: I have Game, Board and Player models in my app.

```
Game -> Board <- Player
```

Game to player is many to many relation through Boards. I'd like to limit that game can have only 2 Boards (therefore only two players).

```
game = Game.create

game.players.push Player.create
game.players.push Player.create
game.players.push Player.create #this line should throw some exception
```

I don't see anything out of the box I could use. One idea is to use validations, but is this the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use ActiveRecord or anything else using ActiveSupport, you could add a custom validation on Board:

```
class Board
  validate :player_count_validation

  has_many :players

  private 

  def player_count_validation
    if players.length > 2
      errors.add(:players, "must have length at most two")
    end
  end
end
```

Then it would work like this:

```
board = Board.new
board.players << Player.create!
board.players << Player.create!
board.players << Player.create! # No exception here
board.save # returns false
board.save! # Raises validation exception
board.errors # Something like { players: ["must have length at most two"] }
board.errors.full_messages # ["Players must have length at most two"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides validations, you could also use a custom method for adding child objects:

```
def add_player(player)
  if players.count < 2
    self.players << player
  else
    raise 'Too many players'
  end
end
```

This does enforce the limit when adding players using this method, but not when accessed directly via association, e.g. `obj.players << player`.